# Why would text be blurry in Excel 2016 under Windows 10 on one PC and not the other?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, cleartype

#### Issue

I am opening the same spreadsheet on two PCs, and the text looks crisp and beautiful even at lower zoom levels (55-100%) on one of them, but blurry at any zoom level ≤88% on the other.

Why would this be the case?

Here is a screenshot of side-by-side comparison

[image: Screenshot.]

with zoom level currently set to 55% in Excel.
(Right window is from a remote desktop session, but when viewed locally it's looking just as good.)

---

#### Notes / things I've tried

- This has stayed pretty much the same over time, after a number of Office and Windows updates on both sides.
- (from [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1380190/why-would-text-be-blurry-in-excel-2016-under-windows-10-on-one-pc-and-not-the-ot#comment2081265_1380190)) This does not seem to be related to any specific font *I'm* using, because apparently Excel is falling back to using some pre-defined font at zoom level ≤88% — note how crisp row/column names are on the "right" PC. This zoom→font change has also been noticed by other people: [one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/15d7ded6-6c1f-4c42-a3d6-4d6cdf9aba32/excel-2010-changing-zoom-from-80-to-78-destroys-fonts?forum=excel), [two](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/4231682).
- In any case, getting it out of the way: the font I'm using on the spreadsheet is *Terminus TTF for Windows* and it's installed on both PCs. It is not defined in any specific style.
  The font in row/column headers is the default Calibri 11 ([defined via Normal style](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/05/01/change-font-in-excel-column-headers/), which I haven't changed).
- Both PCs have a normal-DPI (96?) FullHD display connected, running at native resolution with no scaling (i.e., 100%).
- Excel settings are exactly the same for both installations, and turning hardware acceleration ("Advanced" tab) on or off doesn't seem to make any difference. On the "right" PC, it is turned on.
- I have unsuccessfully tried tweaking the systemwide font smoothing settings using the "Adjust ClearType text" utility, but I'm still experimenting with this.
- "Smooth edges of screen fonts" setting is the same — *on*
  (System → Advanced system settings → Performance Settings → Visual Effects)

Comment: You’re sure both Office installations are the same?

Comment: What happens with a different font?

Comment: What is the zoom level (of the display) set on in Windows?

Comment: @DanielB both are installed to a default location, and versions are close enough to each other to make me think that version doesn't contribute to the issue here. Either way, exact versions are: *left* — Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 64-bit, *right* — Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4738.1000) 64-bit on the right. I may have misunderstood what you meant by installation, in this case could you please elaborate?

Comment: @RobBos it's 100% on both. I implied it when initially writing that the displays are FullHD and normal-DPI, but I updated the post with the info about system zoom level, thanks.

Comment: Just try disabling Hardware Acceleration in Excel options on PC where text appears blur. File --> Options -->advanced --> Display --> Disable hardware graphics acceleration

Comment: @Appleoddity we might be on to something! Selecting a different font allowed to see more clearly that, at lower zoom levels (≤88%), Excel seems to be falling back to some pre-defined font, while retaining the user-set one as expected at zoom levels >88%. **With that, I'm beginning to think that giving the "Adjust ClearType text" utility another go might actually help.**

Comment: @pat2015 thanks for suggestion, unfortunately this didn't make any difference. I also forgot to mention that I compared Excel settings side by side between both installations, and they are exactly the same — updated the question with this.

Comment: Just to check did you try restarting the PC after disabling HW Acceleration?

Comment: The font is probably corrupt. You should try reinstalling it.

Comment: @pat2015 I did. I don't think it's worth disabling it on the "bad" PC though, as it's enabled on the "good" PC.

Comment: @Appleoddity a) the font I'm using for content, b) the font that's used for row/column headers, or c) the font that "a" and "b" fall back to at low zoom levels? I don't know / can't recognize the latter, and "a" and "b" don't seem to matter after our previous findings.

Comment: @Dmitry Trubin Yes certainly, if the setting did not help, you can keep it at its original value